# Cleanest way to write this conditional

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Trying to cut down on long conditionals.
Any suggestion on how could I make this conditional cleaner?

```
 if (!($replacement === null || $replacement === '') && strpos($replacement, 'unknown') === FALSE) {
... 
}
```

Comment: No, I got the logic wrong (or maybe he did).

Comment: `if(!in_array($replacement, ['', null, 'unknown'])){ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Your code will lead to errors if `$replacement` is an array or object (which has no `__toString()` method):

```
hek2mgl@server:~$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > strpos(array(), '');

Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, Array given in php shell code on line 1

Call Stack:
   10.7258     636424   1. {main}() php shell code:0
   10.8469     637640   2. strpos() php shell code:1
```

You need to check if `$replacement` is a string. This makes your code bullet proof in situations where `$replacement` might be an array or object (for whatever bogus reason) and saves you the `=== null` check:

```
if (is_string($replacement) 
    && !empty($replacement)
    && strpos($replacement, 'unknown') === FALSE)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid mixing `||` and `&&` and instead combine all the conditions with `&&`:

```
if (   $replacement !== null 
    && $replacement !== ''
    && strpos($replacement, 'unknown') === FALSE) {
  ...
}
```

This makes it very straight forward to see what conditions are checked in which order.

Answer (score -1):

```
    if ( is_string($replacement)) {
        if ($replacement != "" && $replacement != "unknown") {
        // TODO Here
    }
    }
```